# Angular 5 - what is the equivalent functionality?

Tags: angular, typescript, service, angular5

In my AngularJS 1.5 app I have some controller functions that directly call the service functions.

what would be the equivalent of doing this in Angular?

```
$scope.permissions = ClockingMenuService.permissions;
$scope.data = ClockingMenuService.data;
$scope.decrementWeek = ClockingMenuService.decrementWeek;
$scope.incrementWeek = ClockingMenuService.incrementWeek;
```

in the controller
like just linking the scope function to the service function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you want to expose these methods to the template of a component and that's the reason you're binding them to the `$scope`.

To do this in Angular, you can simply inject this service as a dependency as a public service. Once you've injected as a public service, you can then call these methods right from the component template itself.

Let's say I want these methods to be accessible in my `AppComponent`'s Template. Here's how I can do it:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ClockingMenuService } from 'path-to-the-service';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(public clockingMenuService: ClockingMenuService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.clockingMenuService.permissions);
    console.log(this.clockingMenuService.data);
  }
}
```

Now, in your `app.component.html`, you can the methods on this service like this:

```
<button (click)="clockingMenuService.decrementWeek()">Call decrementWeek</button>
<button (click)="clockingMenuService.incrementWeek()">Call incrementWeek</button>
```

**NOTE**: Exposing the services publicly to the templates is not generally considered a good practice. So you can create method references in the class and then use these references in the templates. Here's what an updated Component would look like:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ClockingMenuService } from 'path-to-the-service';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  decrementWeek;
  incrementWeek;

  constructor(private clockingMenuService: ClockingMenuService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.clockingMenuService.permissions);
    console.log(this.clockingMenuService.data);
    decrementWeek = this.clockingMenuService.decrementWeek;
    incrementWeek = this.clockingMenuService.incrementWeek;
  }
}
```

And here's how the template would look:

```
<button (click)="decrementWeek()">Call decrementWeek</button>
<button (click)="incrementWeek()">Call incrementWeek</button>
```

Comment: Can you also use this approach for data/observables?

Comment: Why not? You can. There would be slight changes though. You might want to ask a separate question for that posting some code though.

Comment: I posted the question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52073989/angular-5-storing-data-in-the-service-instead-of-the-component